# How can I exclude repository endpoints from Open Api through swagger in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, swagger, openapi

I have a problem to show all endpoints containing repository endpoints in swagger when I open localhost:8080/

I don't want to show repository endpoints. What should I define custom endpoints in OpenApiConfig file. I don't want to use @Hidden defining repository above.

Here is the open-api config shown below

```
@Configuration
class OpenApiConfig {

    
    @Value("${application.title}")
    private String title;

    
    @Value("${application.licenseName}")
    private String licenseName;

    
    @Bean
    public OpenAPI customOpenAPI(@Value("${application.description}") String description,
                                 @Value("${application.version}") String version) {
        return new OpenAPI()
                .info(new Info().title(title)
                        .version(version)
                        .description(description)
                        .license(new License().name(licenseName)));
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean with "all endpoints containing repository endpoints"? What happens with your current code and how exactly is that different from what you are expecting?

Comment: @dan1st I show controller endpoints as well as repository endpoints. All repositories are located under com.project.admin_user.repository, com.ays.organization.repository, com.ays.parameter.repository and com.ays.user.repository. I don't want to show repository endpoints. How can I do that?

Comment: Is the package the only difference between repository and other endpoints? Or are they e.g. located under a specific path?

Comment: @dan1st I shared the location where all repositories are defined. com.project is a main package. admin_user, organization, parameter and user are located under main package.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by parameter - Is there any difference in the endpoints themselves (e.g. request path, tags, authentication, etc)?

Comment: @dan1st it contains parameter information for requestbody. My issue is not related with that. How can I revise OpenApiConfig not to show repository endpoints in the swagger?

Comment: It should be possible to modify the paths using `.paths`/`.getPaths()`. However, you would need to somehow be able to differentiate them (for possibly using your parameter information).

Comment: @dan1st Can you handle with that through modifing the paths? Can you give me some code snippets?

Comment: Are the paths for the repository methods different? If so, how?

Comment: All repositories are located under `com.project.admin_user.repository`, `com.project.organization.repository`, `com.project.parameter.repository` and `com.project.user.repository`.

Comment: you can use the annotation @ApiIgnore

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in [this issue](https://github.com/springdoc/springdoc-openapi/issues/210), you can configure which packages to scan in your `application.properties`:

```ini
springdoc.packagesToScan=package1, package2
```

It is also possible to exclude packages with `springdoc.packages-to-exclude`:

```ini
springdoc.packages-to-exclude=com.project.admin_user.repository, com.project.organization.repository, com.project.parameter.repository, com.project.user.repository
```

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue, for me worked to annotate the repository interface with **@RepositoryRestResource(exported = false)**

```
@RepositoryRestResource(exported = false)
public interface ModelRepository extends CrudRepository<Model, Long> {
}
```